# MSACCESS 2016 - Form_Click event doesn't work?

Tags: forms, ms-access, click

I used a simple code on Form_CLick event but nothing happens..
Preview keys property of the form is set to true.

```
Private Sub Form_Click()
MsgBox "ok"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, question is where you are clicking? After running form you click on form sections either on `Detail` section or form `header/footer` or page `header/footer` which is not triggering your sub. See below two sub. In this case if you click on form detail section then you get message box with `Ok from detail.` means triggering  `Detail_Click()` sub. When you click on record selector then you will get `Ok` means triggering `Form_Click()` sub. So, you have to write in specific section to trigger it. May be you are looking for ***`Detail_Click()`*** section sub. Below image for better understanding.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Detail_Click()
    MsgBox "Ok from detail."
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Click()
    MsgBox "Ok"
End Sub
```

[image]